# Sql function to remove values from follower table that are common in unfollow table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, sql-delete

I want to calculate total followers of a person from follow and unfollow table using SQl. Form of table are as follows

Follow table:

[image]

Unfollow table:

[image]

My tries:

1)

```
DELETE FROM follow_table
WHERE follow_table.userid IN (SELECT unfollow_table.userid FROM     unfollow_table) and 
follow_table.Followerid IN (SELECT unfollow_table.Followerid FROM unfollow_table);
```

2. ```
   SELECT userid , Followerid
   FROM follow_table
   MINUS
   SELECT userid , Followerid
   FROM unfollow_table;
   ```

I also tried union and left join but no luck any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Do you want to actually remove the data or return a result set with some rows filtered out?

Comment: I want to return the rows of table 1 which are not common with table 2 and delete those which are common .

Comment: Do you have the CREATE and INSERT statements? I think I have something that will work. I just want to test.

Answer (score 0):

I think the delete you want is

```
DELETE FROM follow_table 
  WHERE (userid, followerid) IN 
  (SELECT userid, followerid
   FROM unfollow_table);
```

This will delete the row with the `userid, followerid` pair in `follow_table` where there is a matching combination of `userid, followerid` in the `unfollow_table`. You may have to turn off safe updates if you do not have the `userid, followerid` pair set as a unique key.

Then the select below should be the one you want, where the "unfollowers" are removed.

```
SELECT *
FROM follow_table;
```

Note, this solution should work in MySQL but might not be valid in other DBMSs. You may have to use an EXIST subquery like the one shown below.

```
DELETE
FROM follow
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT userid, followerid
   FROM unfollow
   WHERE follow.userid = unfollow.userid
     AND follow.followerid = unfollow.followerid);
```